# "linux is NOT supported" when running Docker container

Tags: node.js, docker

So I have the following Dockerfile for my NodeJS project:

```
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm ci --only=production


COPY . .

EXPOSE 80/tcp

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

So far so good. Docker build runs successfully, but when I try to run the container, I get the following:

```
$ docker run myContainer

backend@1.0.0 start
node src/index.js

linux is NOT supported.   <----- THIS right here... ??
```

How can I find out more information regarding this? There is no stack trace, no information or anything to continue from here...

**What I already tried:**

- I tried different base images in my Dockerfile, with the same result.
- My local machine is Windows, So I tried switching docker to linux containers, without any effect.
- I also deployed it to GCP on a Debian. Same result.

Thanks

Comment: It looks like something in your app, that isn't supported on Linux. I don't think it's Docker related.

Comment: It is very possible. But how can I spot it?? there is no stack trace or anything.

Comment: Found the solution, and it was actually on one of my dependencies.
If anyone has a similar issue, you can just "grep" the message in your node_modules folder to find where it is originating.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, and it was actually on one of my dependencies. If anyone has a similar issue, you can just "grep" the message in your node_modules folder to find where it is originating.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the logs to see if there are any more information via `docker logs myContainer`

If the logs doesn't help you can try  running the container with a different version of NodeJS. You can do this by specifying the version in your Dockerfile like so:

```
FROM node:14

WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm ci --only=production


COPY . .

EXPOSE 80/tcp

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

The last thing i can say is try running the container with a different Linux distribution. You can specify the Linux distribution in your Dockerfile using the FROM instruction like the following: `FROM ubuntu:latest`